# Why are sensors transducers when analogue-to-digital-converters (ADC) do the actual conversion?

Tags: transducers

As sensors only sense continuous quantities whereas an ADC is a device which actually converts one form of input to another.

Comment: Please include the question in the body of your post.  The title is intended to be just a short summary.  I don't understand what you mean by "why are sensors transducers?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A sensor is a kind of transducer that converts physical quantity like temp or pressure into electrical signal (voltage, current or charge). ADC converts the electrical signal generated from sensors to an equivalent binary code,  that can be then processed by a logic processor (microcontroller, DSP, FPGA ...).